# How to change duty Cycle in CTC mode in AVR micro controller

Tags: avr, atmega

I would like to know how we can vary the duty cycle in CTC mode in AVR micro controller. In CTC mode, frequency can be varied using OCR0A register (Timer0) assuming some prescaler value. Do we need to make use of OCR0B register (value Must be less than OCR0A) to vary the duty cycle? On OCR0B interrupt, we can change the state of the OCA0 pin I guess.

Comment: Technically, you could use the OCB interrupt to control the other pin, but that defeats the purpose of using the clock modes. In the PWM clock modes, the toggling occurs independent of the processor, that is, "in the background," allowing the processor to operate without interruption. @Spirine has the right idea; use a PWM mode.

Answer (score 1):

The CTC mode only allows you to change the frequency of interrupts/pin state changes.
If you want to drive the duty cycly of a signal instead of its frequency, then you have to use a PWM waveform generation mode.

Comment: What I was referring is we can probably use OCRB to alter duty cycle along with OCRA (to alter Frequency) in CTC mode. On OCRA match, we can set on of the port pin high (Need not be OCA pin). Now setup OCRB such that it is always less than OCRA. On OCRB match, we can just clear the port pin that was set on OCRA match. So OCRB has to be specific % of OCRA so that duty cycle can be varied.

Comment: @MaheshaPadyana From an AVR datasheet, Timer 0 features two __independent__ output compare units. In CTC mode, whenever TCNT0 equals OCR0A or OCR0B, TCNT0 is cleared. I don't say that what you want is impossible, but I assume that it's useless to increase the load of your processor, while you could just use the _background_ PWM mods.

Comment: @Spirine -- nope.  TCNT0 is only cleared at TOP and TOP is set by OCR0A.   ///  The PWM modes can automate setting/clearing at top and clearing/setting at match without interrupts.  You can do a duty cycle with CTC (or with normal), To vary duty cycle, you could set a pin at the OCR0A match and clear it at the OCR0B match, but you have to do stuff with interrupts.